# `Linq` Query contains group join and requires looping throughout Json Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, linq, model-view-controller

Hi I have the following linq query:

```
         var resulta = from a in db.users
         join b in db.userlogin on a.ID equals b.ID into UserGroup
         select new {a.age , a.location , logindetail = UserGroup}

         var resultb = contains other linq data which is irrelvant for this question

          var resultc = new { users = resulta , business = resultb }
```

This all returns json data which is outputted in a MVC View . the razor HTML contains the following :

```
//this loops throughout the user data and find their indexes along with  values
$.each(data.users) , function (index , item) {

//This variable contains an empty string which will be appended to with the following inner loop
var string = '';

// this is a inner loop to search throughout UserGroup
$.each(item.logindetail) , function (index , itema) {
string += <span> + itema.usergroup + itema.email + itema.password + </span>;
```

Before I can appending the following into a div container , the above loop doesn't seem to work , as itema isn't being recognized therefore cannot loop through the individual items in item.logindetail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop object name should be item.logindetail instead you have use item.UserGroup

Comment: Hi it still isn't working even when I'm using item.logindetail? Thank you

Comment: Sorry I was meant to say this works but itema within the function is still returning nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Change the your inner loop.

**New Code:**

```
$.each(item.logindetail) , function (index , itema) {
string += <span> itema.email + itema.password + </span>;
```

Comment: This works however itema within the function is still returning nothing?

Comment: try **console.log(itema);** to check what you have got. If your are not getting email and password, then check your response.

Comment: callback is undefined , which seems odd as the item should exist? Thank you

Comment: please post your response of resulta .